# Filter products based on searchString and product size

Tags: reactjs

I'm rather new to React and still learning. I'm trying to filter my overview of products based on a search string and/or with a filter based on the size state.

Right now, the searching works and I'm able to search within this product view
[image]
[image]

My search works this way: I take the value from the input and insert it into the `{this.state.plants.filter` you can see in the bottom of the sample code below.

**My question is:** How do I filter the products by `this.state.size` AND `this.state.searchString` at the same time?

**OR:** Leave the `this.state.searchString` empty and only applying `this.state.size`?

I hope my question makes sense.

```
this.state = {
    plants: '',
    title: '',
    size: '',
    searchString: '',
    filterSize: ''
};
    
handleSearch = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        searchString: event.target.value
    })
}

handleSizeFilter = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        filterSize: event.target.value
    })
}
    
// Search input
<input type="text" className="search" placeholder="Søg" onChange={this.handleSearch} value={this.state.searchString} />
        
// Size Filter Button
<button onClick={handleSizeFilter} value="22">Size 22</button>
        
{this.state.plants.filter(plant => plant.title.includes(this.state.searchString)).map(plant => (
    {plant.title} - {plant.size}
))}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do here is something like:

```js
let filteredPlants = this.state.plants;
const { searchString, filterSize } = this.state;

if (searchString) {
  filteredPlants = filteredPlants.filter(plant => plant.title.includes(searchString);
}

if (typeof filterSize === 'number') {
  filteredPlants = filteredPlants.filter(plant => plant.size === filterSize);
}
```

NOTE: Since this is a potentially expensive operation depending on how big your arrays are, best to create a method inside your class component and wrap it in a utility function like [memoizeOne](https://github.com/alexreardon/memoize-one).

If you put this inside your `render` method, the component will iterate through the array every time you re-render - so in your case every single time you type or delete something in your input fields